# Mutual information of discrete and continous stochastic variable

Tags: measure-theory, information-theory

As part of a homework, I have a "quantizer" consisting of variables $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ which have the following joint distribution.

[image]

$X_2$ is discrete and I can assume that all probabilities are uniform.

Now I am supposed to calculate the mutual information $I(X_1;X_2) = h(X_1) + h(X_2) - h(X_1,X_2)$ and interpret the result. $h(X)$ is the [differential entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy) of $X$.

But according to the book(Elements of Information Theory, p. 229):
"The differential entropy of a discrete random variable can be considered to be $-\infty$"

When I plug this into my equation, I get:
$I(X_1;X_2) = h(X_1) + (-\infty) - (-\infty)$

How do I interpret that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: it's easier to use $I(X_1; X_2) = h(X_1) - h(X_1|X_2)$.

Hint2: $p(X_1|X_2 = 1)$ is a continuous distribution.

Comment: Ok, but won't that give me the same problem? h(X1|X2) is still a combination of discrete and continuous. Or am I allowed to do something like **h(X1|X2) = h(X1,X2) - h(X2) = h(X1,X2) - H(X2)**. Because if I treat X2 as continuous I get an integral over an infinitely small area, which gives me problems when trying to evaluate h(X1,X2) as well.

Comment: Did you see my hint2?

Comment: Isn't much easier to do $h(X_2) - h(X_2 |X_1)$ instead?

Comment: @leonbloy Sure. That's much easier. I just wanted to avoid dealing with delta functions.

Comment: Thank you, it really helped me understand the solution even though the deadline for the homework is long since past. I'm sorry for the late reply, I've had two quite study-intensive weeks...